# Prokaryotic Ribosomes

Tags: microbiology

During bacterial protein synthesis, when ribosomes attach to the cytoplasmic membrane and form a polysome, to what molecule are the ribosomes attaching? Is the polysome held to the cytoplasmic membrane by just a single connection between one ribosome and the particular attachment molecule?

Comment: Do "ribosomes attach to the cytoplasmic membrane"? [Membrane-bound Ribosomes Define the Rough ER.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26841/#A2204) [Ribosomes are not membrane bound.](https://www.boundless.com/microbiology/bacteria-archaea-and-eukaryote-cell-structure/specialized-internal-structures-of-prokaryotes/ribosomes/) A [polysome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysome) represents a cluster of ribosomes, bound to a mRNA molecule.

Comment: Here is a good article on bacterial protein synthesis: http://mmbr.asm.org/content/69/1/101.full

Comment: According to "Microbiology: An Introduction" by Batzing, Ch. 2 p. 24, "During protein synthesis, bacterial ribosomes attach to the cytoplasmic membrane.."

Answer (score 2):

According to [Smith et al., 1978](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC411347/), bacterial ribosomes don't necessarily bind directly to the membrane, but through the nascent chain, in which case nothing is truly attaching to anything..